# Verify Contract Code Eth

Tags: tokens, cpp-ethereum, verify, contract-verification

I'm trying to verify an erc20 Contract code for a few days.
I have read a lot and tried but just can not get on. maybe someone can help me?

**Here are the dates:**

```
/*
Implements EIP20 token standard: https://github.com/ethereum/EIPs/blob/master/EIPS/eip-20.md
.*/
pragma solidity ^0.4.18;

import "./EIP20Interface.sol";


contract Doi is EIP20Interface {

  uint256 constant private MAX_UINT256 = 2**256 - 1;
  mapping (address => uint256) public balances;
  mapping (address => mapping (address => uint256)) public allowed;
  /*
  NOTE:
  The following variables are OPTIONAL vanities. One does not have to include them.
  They allow one to customise the token contract & in no way influences the core functionality.
  Some wallets/interfaces might not even bother to look at this information.
  */
  string public name;                   //fancy name: eg Simon Bucks
  uint8 public decimals;                //How many decimals to show.
  string public symbol;                 //An identifier: eg SBX

  function Doi(
    uint256 _initialAmount,
    string _tokenName,
    uint8 _decimalUnits,
    string _tokenSymbol
    ) public {
    balances[msg.sender] = _initialAmount;               // Give the creator all initial tokens
    totalSupply = _initialAmount;                        // Update total supply
    name = _tokenName;                                   // Set the name for display purposes
    decimals = _decimalUnits;                            // Amount of decimals for display purposes
    symbol = _tokenSymbol;                               // Set the symbol for display purposes
  }

  function transfer(address _to, uint256 _value) public returns (bool success) {
    require(balances[msg.sender] >= _value);
    balances[msg.sender] -= _value;
    balances[_to] += _value;
    Transfer(msg.sender, _to, _value);
    return true;
  }

  function transferFrom(address _from, address _to, uint256 _value) public returns (bool success) {
    uint256 allowance = allowed[_from][msg.sender];
    require(balances[_from] >= _value && allowance >= _value);
    balances[_to] += _value;
    balances[_from] -= _value;
    if (allowance < MAX_UINT256) {
      allowed[_from][msg.sender] -= _value;
    }
    Transfer(_from, _to, _value);
    return true;
  }

  function balanceOf(address _owner) public view returns (uint256 balance) {
    return balances[_owner];
  }

  function approve(address _spender, uint256 _value) public returns (bool success) {
    allowed[msg.sender][_spender] = _value;
    Approval(msg.sender, _spender, _value);
    return true;
  }

  function allowance(address _owner, address _spender) public view returns (uint256 remaining) {
    return allowed[_owner][_spender];
  }
}
```

**And the Bytecode**

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

**Etherscan.io**

https://etherscan.io/token/0x3c9a7bfceed84367b51cf34bd75b6cdeead1b79b

**Github**

https://gist.github.com/bd07804ad24d2661d81bf734790c30c9

Comment: what's the question?

Comment: ^ plus if you have tried lots of things, please include them in the question

Comment: ^ I tried, but it seems to be something else. Unfortunately, this is my first contract and my knowledge seems to reach its limits. The token is for a friend and his project, which of course I join in. But it seems to me as if it will fail due to the contract verify. I'm not smart enough to spot the mistake. also merging into a single ... .sol was not successful. The whole project and my friend depend on this verification. But I have no plan ....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are trying to verify a contract code on etheracan, try to put all the imported file into one full  .sol file. Then copy the whole smart contract where is required, put the correct compiler version, contract name and optimization and it will work!

Comment: Contract Code Fail... Have make all new, and Verify is OK. (into one full) THX

Comment: No prob mate enjoy:)